# how to get rid of KeyError: 'kivy.garden.matplotlib'?

Tags: python, android, matplotlib, kivy, runtime-error

i am using `matplotlib with kivy`   when i am running my file i am getting this error can anyone suggest something.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/root/pycharm-2019.3.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
     pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
   File "/root/pycharm-2019.3.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
     exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
   File "/root/PycharmProjects/vsts/venv/main.py", line 17, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
   File "/root/pycharm-2019.3.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
     module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 640, in _load_backward_compatible
 KeyError: 'kivy.garden.matplotlib'
```

Comment: Have you installed the garden flower?

Comment: I have installed but no change in error

Comment: Can you post a minimal runnable code example that produces the error?

Comment: Yes, I got that KeyError too

Comment: You need to `garden install matplotlib` and pip install `matplotlib`

Comment: But I have installed that using pycharm, is it working in yours??

Comment: yes It is working, thankyou so much for helping me

Answer (score 1):

use these commands it helped mine that had error for
`from kivy.garden.matplotlib` :

python 3.7 using anaconda

1. pip install kivy
2. pip install kivy-garden
3. garden install matplotlib
4. pip install matplotlib==2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would clone "https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib" to the "virt(directory with your virtual environment)/lib/python/kivy/garden/"
"git clone [https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib"](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib%22)
and rename the directory "garden.matplotlib" to the "matplotlib"

Answer (score 0):

There is altarnative way to display any matplotlib graph in Kivy. Use python self module io() like,

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image,CoreImage      #for create a image with coreimage

import io   #I used io it's simple and useful!

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   #need matplotlib library

kivy=Builder.load_string("""

<Image_Example>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
   
        Button:
            id:click
            text:'display image'
            on_press:root.display_img()  #when it click display image
        Label:
            text:'That is your image'

        Image:
            id:img
            source:''  #image source
           
            allow_stretch:True
           
            keep_ratio:True

""")

class Image_Example(BoxLayout):

    def display_img(self):
        X=[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        Y= [5, 14, 7, 20, 11]  #your dataset
       
        plt.plot(X,Y)  #craete yourdataset graph
        plt.title("title here")
        plt.xlabel("x-axis label here)")
        plt.ylabel("y-axis label here")
       
        buf=io.BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buf)  #save your dataset to IoByte
       
        buf.seek(0) #seek your graph
        self.ids.img.texture=CoreImage(buf, ext="png").texture     #display your image
        self.ids.img.reload()
        del buf #then delete created buf

class ImageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Image_Example()
       

kv=ImageApp().run()
```

https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/c/Z5RC-j2r3pU/m/1fD1h6BLAwAJ?pli=1